# How to convert numerical claims to first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

A). There are atmost 2 apples ?

B). There are exactly 2 apples ?

C). There is atmost 1 apple ?

D). There is exactly 1 apple ?

---

Is there any procedure to convert these type of english sentences as generally we have "For All" and "There Exists" in the sentences, but how is this different ?

Comment: $\exists$ has to be read "There is *at least* one..."; with it and *equality* you have to build up the otehrs

Comment: Example for "exactly two" : $\exists x \exists y (x \ne y \ldots \land \forall z (\ldots z=x \lor z=y))$

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here are some possible ways to make these kinds of numerical claims in general:

**'At least n' (Method 1)**

"There is at least 1 P" : $\exists x P(x)$

"There are at least 2 P's" : $\exists x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y)$

"There are at least 3 P's" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z (P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

Etc.

Note that with this method you need to use $n \choose 2$ non-identity claims (in addition to $n$ $P$ claims) so that increases rather quickly (e.g. to express there are at least 10 P's, we would need 45 non-identity statements!  ... can we improve on that? Yes! But first let's discuss 'at most':

**'At most n' (Method 1)**

One method to do 'at most n' is to deny 'at least n+1'. So:

"There is at most 1 P": $\neg \exists x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y)$

If you bring the negation inside, this is equivalent to: $\forall x \forall y ((P(x) \land P(y)) \rightarrow x = y)$

"There are at most 2 P's": $\neg \exists x \exists y \exists z (P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

Again, bringing the negation inside you get:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z)) \rightarrow (x = y \lor x = z \lor y = z))$ ... which is what goblin did!

Etc.

OK, so here we get even more (non-)identity statements: $n+1 \choose 2$ (in addition to n+1 $P$ claims). Later we will see how we can do this more efficiently, but first:

**'Exactly n' (Method 1)**

One method is to recognize that 'Exactly n' is equivalent to 'at least n and at most n'. Doing a straightforward conjunction, we thus get:

"There is exactly 1 P" : $\exists x P(x) \land \neg \exists x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y)$

or, equivalently: $\exists x P(x) \land \forall x \forall y ((P(x) \land P(y)) \rightarrow x = y)$

"There are exactly 2 P's" : $\exists x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y) \land \neg \exists x \exists y \exists z (P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z)$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y) \land \forall x \forall y \forall z ((P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z)) \rightarrow (x = y \lor x = z \lor y = z))$

Etc.

**'Exactly n' (Method 2)**

OK, so these claims get really big really fast. Can we do better? Yes. In stead of just conjuncting the 'at least' and 'at most' claims, let's integrate these two ideas: To say there are exactly $n$ P's, we can say that there are $n$ different P's ... but no others:

"There is exactly 1 P" : $\exists x (P(x) \land \neg \exists y (P(y) \land x \not = y))$

or, equivalently: $\exists x (P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow x = y))$

"There are exactly 2 P's" : $\exists x (\exists y (P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y) \land \neg \exists z (P(z) \land z \not = x \land z \not = y))$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y ((P(x) \land P(y) \land x \not = y) \land \forall z (P(z) \rightarrow (z = x \lor z = y)))$

"There are exactly 3 P's" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z ((P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \neg \exists w (P(w) \land w \not = x \land w \not = y \land w \not = z))$

or, equivalently: $\exists x \exists y \exists z ((P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \forall w (P(w) \rightarrow (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z)))$

Etc.

Interestingly, we see that in the second half of the statement, we no longer get $n+1 \choose 2$ (non-)identity claims plus $n+1$ $P$ claims, but merely $n$ (non-)identity claims and exactly one $P$ claim, because we end up saying: once you have your $n$ different P's, then any P is one of the $n$ objects, so you can't have any more than $n$.  This is an idea that we can use to write the 'at least' and 'at most' claims more efficiently as well:

**'At most n' (Method 2)**

As just observed, we can say that there are exactly $n$ P's by saying that if you already have $n$ different P's, you can't get any other $P$. But to say that there are 'at most' $n$ P's, we don't have to require those $n$ P's to be different. In fact, we don;t even have to require that they be P's: we can simply say that we can pick $n$ objects, that may or may not be different, and that may or may not be P's, such that there is no object that is different from all those, and that is a P. So:

'There is at most one P' : $\exists x \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow y = x)$

Again, notice that I am not saying that $x$ *is* a P ... this statement would also be true if there are not any P's at all (of course, I do need a non-empty domain, but that assumption is typically built into our logic systems). However, any P's that do exist will have to be the same ... hence there is at most 1 P.

"There are at most 2 P's" : $\exists x \exists y \forall z (P(z) \rightarrow (z = x \lor z = y))$

Again, this is not saying that $x$ and $y$ are P's, but they could be. And I am also not claiming that $x$ and $y$ are different ... but they could be. Hence, you can have 0,1, or 2 different P's, but you definitely can't have 3 or more!

"There are at most 3 P's" : $\exists x \exists y \exists z \forall w (P(w) \rightarrow (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

Etc.

So, in general, the claim is that there are $n$ objects such that any $P$ has to be one of those objects, and that means that you can't have more than $n$ P's.

The nice thing about this expression is that it uses exactly $n$ identity statements, so it is quite a bit more efficient to write than the first method for expressing 'at most', especially for large n. In fact, you only have to use exactly one $P$ predicate, instead of $n$.

**'At least n' (Method 2)**

We pointed out earlier that 'at most n' is the negation of 'at least n+1', but that also means that 'at least n+1' is the negation of 'at most n'.

So:

"There are at least 2 P's": $\neg \exists x \forall y (P(y) \rightarrow y = x)$ which is equivalent to $\forall x \exists y (P(y) \land y \not = x)$

The latter statement says that for whatever object $x$ I pick, I can always find a different object that is a P. So, if there would be only one P, then that wouldn't be true, since I can pick that P for the $x$, and now there is no different $y$ that is also a $P$. So, you need at least 2 P's to make this true.

"There are at least 3 P's": $\neg \exists x \exists y \forall z (P(z) \rightarrow (z = x \lor z = y))$ which is equivalent to: $\forall x \forall y \exists z (P(z) \land z \not = x \land z \not= y)$

Etc.

To say that there are at least $n$ P's, we can say that no matter how you pick $n-1$ objects (so even if those are all different and all P's), you can always find an object different from all those, and that is a P.

And, once again, this method saves us a lot of writing: only $n-1$ identity claims plus 1 $P$ claim.

**'Exactly n' (Method 3)**

In the second method for 'exactly n', we saw that a claim like "There are exactly 3 P's" translated into:

$\exists x \exists y \exists z (P(x) \land P(y) \land P(z) \land x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \forall w (P(w) \rightarrow (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

Thus, while in the second half we reduce the number of identity and $P$ statements in comparison to the first method, we still get $3 \choose 2$ non-identity claims, and $n$ $P$ claims in the first half. Now, one trick to get rid of all the $P$ claims in the first half is to do this:

"There is exactly 1 P" : $\exists x \forall y (P(y) \leftrightarrow x = y)$

"There are exactly 2 P's" : $\exists x \exists y (x \not = y \land \forall z (P(z) \leftrightarrow (z = x \lor z = y))$

"There are exactly 3 P's" :

$\exists x \exists y \exists z ( x \not = y \land x \not = z \land y \not = z \land \forall w (P(w) \leftrightarrow w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

That is, by using a biconditional, any of the existentially quantified objects will have to be a $P$, so we don;t have to individually specify this.

Of course, the drawback of this method is that we still have $n \choose 2$ non-identity claims.

**'Exactly n' (Method 4)**

Especially for large $n$ then, the most efficient way to express 'exactly n' seems to be the conjunction of the efficient ways to expressing 'at least n' and 'at most n'. That is:

"There are exactly 2 P's" : $\forall x \exists y (P(y) \land y \not = x) \land \exists x \exists y \forall z (P(z) \rightarrow (z = x \lor z = y))$

"There are exactly 3 P's" : $\forall x \forall y \exists z (P(z) \land z \not = x \land z \not= y) \land \exists x \exists y \exists z \forall w (P(w) \rightarrow (w = x \lor w = y \lor w = z))$

(ok, so these two are not any more efficient than earlier ones, but again, once $n$ gets large, this method will be most efficient, as it has $2n-1$ non-identity claims, and 2 $P$ claims.)

Wow, ok, so that turned out to be a *much* larger post than I intended, sorry!

Comment: Thanks !! A beautiful explaination :)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation @Bram28. Does anyone know if such methods could be found in some literature? If so, a reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Such a beautiful answer. Piece of Masterstroke.

Answer (score 1):

A) $\forall(x, y,z)(\mathrm{isApple}(x) \wedge \mathrm{isApple}(y) \wedge \mathrm{isApple}(z) \rightarrow x = y \vee x=z \vee y=z)$

For B), start off by expressing "there's at least two apples", then take the conjunction with the above sentence.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. I mean logic behind A and B ?

Comment: @Garrick, first translate the sentence I wrote into English, and see if it makes sense. If not, come back and ask me again.