# How can I express the "uniqueness quantifier" without "$\exists!$"?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I am trying to express the sentence as a logical statement using quantifiers and without using "$\exists!$":

"There is a dog who has exactly one favorite toy."

My first question that has me stuck is should I make my propositional function a function of two variables $L(x,y)= \text{"$x$ has a favorite toy $y$}."$ ($x$ for all dogs and $y$ for all toys), or is there a way to do this by just using one variable $L(x)=\text{"$x$ has one favorite toy"}$. I don't know why I'm so stumped by this but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: $\exists!xPx$ is the same as $(\exists xPx)\wedge((Px\wedge Py)\implies(x=y))$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037209/how-to-convert-numerical-claims-to-first-order-logic/2037698#2037698 for how to symbolize numerical claims like 'exactly $n$', 'at least $n$', or 'at most $n$'

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 10):

An efficient way to express $\exists ! x \ P(x)$ is:

$$\exists x \forall y (P(y) \leftrightarrow y =x)$$

So, if we use $D(x)$ for '$x$ is a dog', and $F(x,y)$ for '$x$ has $y$ as a favorite toy', your sentence can be symbolized as:

$$\exists x (D(x) \land \exists y \forall z (F(x,z)  \leftrightarrow z =y))$$

Comment: How would you say your statement ∃(()∧∃∀((,)↔=)) using words? Would it be, "There exists a dog and there exists a toy y such that for all toys z, the dog x has a favorite toy y if and only if the favorite toy y is equal to toy z."?

Comment: @Evan Good question .. it is indeed hard to put into English, though I would try it with an 'all and only' .. so maybe "There is a dog whose favorite toys are all and only this one object"

Comment: @evan “There exists a dog x and a toy y, such that a toy is a favorite of dog x if and only if it is toy y.”  I personally would have written $F(x,z) \to z=y$ instead of $\leftrightarrow$; in this context it is equivalent.  Then, “if a toy is a favorite of dog x, then it is toy y”

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be variables and $P$ be a predicate.

You can split up *there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$* into two claims.

- There exists at least one $x$ such that $P(x)$ .
- If $P(x)$ and $P(y)$, then $x=y$ .

More concretely.

$$ \exists! x \mathop. P(x) \iff (\exists z \mathop . P(z)) \mathop\land (\forall x \mathop. \forall y \mathop. (P(x) \land P(y)) \to x =y)$$

Comment: I think you have made a typo. Should not that read $ \exists! x \mathop. P(x) \iff (\exists z \mathop . P(z)) \mathop\land (\forall x \mathop. \forall y \mathop. \color{red}{P(x) \land P(y)} \to x =y)$?

Comment: I mentioned that $\to$ is intended to be right-associative. $a \to b \to c$ is equivalent to $(a \land b) \to c$ .

Comment: I think relying on associativity of an operator was a bad idea, so I changed the formula based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you too. -

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use just 1 variable "$L(x)$=$x$ has 1 favourite toy", or even two variables "$L(x,y)$=$x$ has 1 favourite $y$" however it is a better learning experience to specify what you mean by exactly 1.

A sufficient way to express "There is a dog who has exactly one favorite toy," in symbolic logic is the following $(1)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\exists x\big(\exists y(D(x)\land T(y)\land F(x,y)\land\forall z((F(x,z)\land T(z))\rightarrow z=y))\big),
\end{equation}

where $D(x)$ expresses "$x$ is a dog", $T(y)$ "$y$ is a toy", and $F(x,y)$ "$x$'s favorite toy is $y$."

The way $(1)$ works is that it asserts that there is a dog $x$, a toy $y$ and the dogs favorite toy is $y$. Then it goes on to assert, that any toy which is the dogs favorite, is the same toy as the first. Thus there is only 1 toy.

---

For your future reference, I have included the definitions of less than, greater than or equal to, and exactly 1 below this answer.

**Less than n:**

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall x_1\dots\forall x_{n-1}\forall x_n((x_1\neq x_2\land\dots\land x_{n-1}\neq x_n)\rightarrow \lnot P(x_1)\lor\dots\lor\lnot P(x_{n-1})\lor\lnot P(x_n))
\end{equation}

**Greater than or equal to n:**

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\exists x_1\dots\exists x_{n-1}\exists x_n(x_1\neq x_2\land\dots\land x_{n-1}\neq x_n\land P(x_1)\land\dots\land P(x_{n-1})\land P(x_n))
\end{equation}

**Exactly 1**

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\exists x(P(x)\land\forall y(P(y)\rightarrow y=x))
\end{equation}