# How to write the logical form for unique entities

Tags: logic

I am curious how we write in simple predicate logic the statements.

I know that the statement
"there is a window in the bathroom" can be represented (using IN as a predicate):

∃x(W(x) ∧ In(x, Bathroom))

What would I write if I wanted to say there are 2 or 4 windows in the bathroom, using IN as a predicate?

Comment: Here is a long post I created for symbolizing numerical claims like 'exactly 2', 'at least 5', or 'at most 17': https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037209/how-to-convert-numerical-claims-to-first-order-logic/2037698#2037698

Comment: See [Uniqueness quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification).